# Slim framework 404 and rout erros

Tags: frameworks, routes, http-status-code-404, slim

I am writing an API with Slim Framework but I've been getting 404 error

```php
require ('Slim/Slim/Slim.php');
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->response()->header('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8');   

$app->get('/', 'test'); // It is OK and I can see the return of my function "test" when I access domain/api

$app->get('/groups', 'getGroups'); // 404 error while I try to go to domain/api/groups
```

Someone know how to fix this route problem ?

Comment: Did you fix your problem? I updated my answer to really answer to your question..

Comment: Yes Thanks, I would like to vote your answer but i do not have reputation to do it. Sorry =/

Comment: You could accept my answer - described here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a htaccess issue. That [htaccess](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim#apache) must be placed in your api folder.

```htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```